# Flutter. Set parent's height based on child canvas drawing's

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is there any way to set parent container's height based on height of what is drawn in the child canvas?

I am using a custom painter like this:

```
 double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

 return Container(
  color: Colors.yellow,
  height: 240,
  width: width,
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: ShapePainter(),
  ),
);
```

Then `ShapePainter()` draws different shapes (1 shape for each canvas in the list).

[image]

But as you can see, some shapes like 2nd rectangle, take twice the space they actually need.
I can calculate height of a shape inside `ShapePainter()` easily,
but I have no idea how to apply it to its parent's height. *(Except calling an insta-setState() from child, but there should be a better way, because this may flicker for one frame)*

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are setting the height of the `Container` to `240`, so the container will always be that. If you get rid of the explicit height setting, the parent widget (the `Container`) will adjust to the intrinsic height of the child. Or do I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @TimKlingeleers No it won't. Without 240 its 0, because for some reason flutter can't determine intrinsic height of canvas drawings. Or maybe it somehow can(Which I hope it is), but Its not "default" behavior.

Comment: Can you try this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47617#issuecomment-633059515. Seems to be related. Or the example a few comments before that one.

Comment: @TimKlingeleers didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter has several phases that it goes through when creating a frame, including building, layout, and painting. The size of widgets is determined during the layout phase. So you can't set the height based it what was painted. (Except, as you've said, by using something like `setState` to generate a new frame.) You'll have to determine the the size you want before any painting has happened. For example, you can give your CustomPainter a getter to provide the shape:

```dart
class ShapePainter extends CustomPainter {
  ShapePainter({@required this.shape});

  final Shape shape;

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // the painting
  }

  Size get size {
    // determine size based on shape
  }
}

...

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final shapePainter = ShapePainter();

  return Container(
    color: Colors.yellow,
    height: shapePainter.size.height,
    align: Alignment.center,
    child: CustomPaint(
      painter: shapePainter,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution. I was overcomplicating things.